# Why does this code call keyup() at the end of the block?

Tags: jquery

I am having a doubt of the code below

```
$("input").keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("p").text(value);
}).keyup();
```

What is the use of `.keyup()` function at the end of the script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.keyup(function () {...})` registers an eventhandler, `keyup()` immediately triggers the event.

explanation:

Since the keyup event writes the input-value to a separate p element, this will be triggered directly on pageload. (ty rory) This method is called chaining and a nice way to reduce code.

Comment: Just to make it clear, the point of the last `keyup()` is to fill the `p` element with the text of the `input` on page load.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery lets you chain function calls. The above code is equivalent to:

```
$("input").keyup(function () {
   var value = $(this).val();
   $("p").text(value);
});

$("input").keyup();
```

So the second call triggers the event.

Answer (score 4):

`.keyup();` is short for `.trigger('keyup')`. It will trigger the event and execute the event handler.

Note that the event will be "fake" - no key will actually be released and you can’t get any keyCodes from the event object.